# Render lists of posts grouped by date

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-itertools

My site has multiple posts per day.  I want to render a list of posts, but I want the posts grouped by date, not just sorted by date, so that each date has its own list of posts.

I send a list of posts to the template, and `post.posted_on` is the timestamp when the post was created.  How do I render the posts grouped by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the posts by day.  Sort the posts by `posted_on` in descending order, then use `groupby` with a key for the day.  Iterate over the groups, and iterate over the posts within each group, to build sections with lists of posts.

```
from itertools import groupby
# sort posts by date descending first
# should be done with database query, but here's how otherwise
posts = sorted(posts, key=lambda: post.posted_on, reverse=True)
by_date = groupby(posts, key=post.posted_on.date)
return render_template('posts.html', by_date=by_date)
```

```html
{% for date, group in by_date %}<div>
    <p>{{ date.isoformat() }}</p>
    {% for post in group %}<div>
        {{ post.title }}
        ...
    </div>{% endfor %}
</div>{% endfor %}
```